# Optional argument in Argparse (how to make optional argument to work with specific field)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am having the below requirement using Argparse.
**My code:**

```
def main(argv=None):
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
parser.add_argument("--svc_only", nargs="?", const=True, metavar="", help="")

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--a", nargs="?", const=True, default=False, choices=["--svc_only"], help="")
group.add_argument("--b", nargs="?", const=True, default=False, choices=["--svc_only"],help="")
group.add_argument("--c", action='store_true', help="")
group.add_argument("--cmd", nargs='+', help="")
parser.add_argument("--loc", help="")

parser.set_defaults(func=handle_op)
args = parser.parse_args(argv)
print("args",args)
return args.func(args)
```

Problem: I am using `mutually_exclusive_group` so It is working fine and I can use any one command from the group but for **--svc_only** I want It to work only with **--a** optional argument.

that is

```
python3 abc.py --a --svc_only
```

//It is working fine but this --svc_only can be passed to any command registered in the group for example `python3 abc.py --b --svc_only`. (How to restrict to use it with specific positional argument).

I have checked about the sub parser but seems like It was not working with `--` (optional argument)

for example

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import argparse
    def main(argv=None):
        # create the top-level parser
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command")
    
        pcyc = subparser.add_parser("--a", help="Restrat SPUS")
        pcyc.add_argument("--svc_only",nargs="?", const=True, metavar="", help="Scale down stateful set")
    
        stop = subparser.add_parser("--b", help="Restrat SPUS")
        stop.add_argument("--svc_only", nargs="?", const=True, metavar="", help="Scale down stateful set")
    
        args = parser.parse_args(argv)
        print("args",args)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()


python .\testCase1.py --a
usage: testCase1.py [-h] {--a,b} ...
testCase1.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --a
```

Comment: Nothing in `argparse` to handle this.

Comment: What is '--pcyc' supposed to match?  Also subparser names shouldn't have '--'. Subparsers is overkill for your needs.

Comment: sorry I have updated It is python .\testCase1.py --a

Comment: As I wrote, '--a' is not a valid subparser name.  It's treated as a optional's flag, as in your original code.